# Validations getting hidden

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I have this Asp.Net webforms code:

```
 <div class="content-wrapper">
            <asp:Panel runat="server">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ValidationGroup="fgEm1" ControlToValidate="txt1" ErrorMessage="Required" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Confirm my email" ValidationGroup="fgEm1" CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnConfirm1" />
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Panel runat="server">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="fgEm2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt2" ErrorMessage="Required" />
                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Confirm my email" ValidationGroup="fgEm2" CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnConfirm2" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
```

When I click on the 1st button I get required which is fine. Now when I click on 2nd button I see required next to the 2nd textbox but the 1st one gets hidden. I do not want that. I want the 1st one should stay as it is.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: First, you have two validation groups. That means you have told it to behave exactly like it  does. The easiest way though is to add a second required field validator for txt1, but use the validationgroup fgEm2. That way it validates for the first button, then the second button will validate both txt2 and txt1.

Comment: @Mark: You are entirely changing the how validation groups work. What I want is really simple. Since it it two validation groups, the other group should be independent of the 1st group and so if we have validation message on the 1st group it should stay as it is when 2nd group's button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

When btnConfirm2 clicked only validation controls that are a part of fgEm2 are validated, similarly btnConfirm1 clicked only validation controls that are a part of fgEm1 are validated.
If you want to validate both controls at a time then you have to force them to check all the validation control for that you cloud use javascript or in button click check both validation:

**Javascript:**

```
 function fnJSOnFormSubmit() {
        var isGrpOneValid = Page_ClientValidate("fgEm1");
        var isGrpTwoValid = Page_ClientValidate("fgEm2");
if (isGrpOneValid && isGrpTwoValid)
            return true; //postback only when BOTH validations pass.
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and call this function onclientclick event.

**Button Click Event:**

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  { 
    switch (((Button)sender).ID)
    {
      case "btnConfirm1":
        if (RequiredFieldValidator1.IsValid)//RequiredFieldValidator1 is the ID of first validator 
        {
          // write your code
        }
        else
        {
          //Write your code.
        }
        break;
      case "btnConfirm2 ":
        if (RequiredFieldValidator2.IsValid && RequiredFieldValidator1.IsValid)// RequiredFieldValidator2 is the ID of second validator 
        {
          //do your code
        }
        else
        {
         //do your code
        }
        break;
      default:
      //do your code
      break;

    }
  }
```

this set of code also help you out

```
     var i;
            for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) { 
                ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i]); //this forces validation in all groups
            }
 // use this inside javascript function or in buttonclick event
```

This link will help you out more:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

@Jack I am not changing how validation groups work at all. Validation groups are a group of validators, not controls. The absolute simplest thing you could do would be this small change:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
        <asp:Panel runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ValidationGroup="fgEm1" ControlToValidate="txt1" ErrorMessage="Required" display="dynamic" />
```

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="fgEm2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt2" ErrorMessage="Required" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Confirm my email" ValidationGroup="fgEm2" CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="btnConfirm2" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

With dynamic display set the validators swap out easily. Keeping the first one visible when it is not within the group of the second button violates how validation groups work.